# Python code for exctracting data from a query

Tags: python, client

I use the following code for extracting data from a query, but what is returned is the summary of the data not the whole data. in the last line of the code, the 70d shows data for last 70 days, but what is extracted and saved in the file is only the summary not the whole 9492 rows of data. Can you help me resolve this problem please?

```
import influxdb
import pandas as pd

host = 'data.open-storm.org'
port = 8086
database = 'DFW'
username = 'grafana_daemon'
password = 'ExrcisWholesalEntranc'

client = influxdb.DataFrameClient(host=host, port=port, database=database, 
username=username, password=password)

with open('test.txt', 'w') as a:
    a.write('%s: 05' % client.query("SELECT value FROM maxbotix_depth WHERE 
    node_id='DFW007' AND time > now() - 70d"))
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'summary'? Can you post what is being written to the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing `DataFrameClient` with `InfluxDBClient`.

The [DataFrameClient](http://influxdb-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api-documentation.html#dataframeclient) returns a pandas DataFrame. Pandas options for [display.max_rows](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html) default is usually set to `60` which is probably how many rows you currently get. If you can figure out how to tell InfluxDB to set its 
`pd.options.display.max_rows` to a higher value that may work and allow you to continue using the `DataFrameClient`.

On the other hand, using the `InfluxDBClient` returns a full [ResultSet](http://influxdb-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api-documentation.html#resultset) which contains all (approx. 9492?) rows you are expecting.

Hope this helps.